# Relaying all domains to a relay host with postfix

Tags: postfix

I am trying to setup a backup mail server to hold any incoming mail in the event that the main mail server is down. I found a guide on doing this but it assumes you are only working with one domain so that is specified as a relay domain.

However, there could be many domains cnamed to our mail server and I don't really want to maintain a database of these for postfix to lookup.

So the question is whether I can forward everything to the main server (holding mail locally if it can't be delivered) but avoiding the issue where email addressed to the local hostname gets caught up in that as well which could cause an email loop with any bounced emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your backup mail server to use your main mail server as a smarthost via the `relayhost` configuration directive. This will cause all mails which are *not* adressed locally to the backup mail server to be forwarded to your main mail server, including the domains hosted on your main mail server but also all external domains. Note that this will prevent outgoing mails from being sent while your main mail server is down.

Comment: That sounds great. Just to make sure though, what happens if the server needs to return an error to the sender of an incoming email (perhaps SPF fail or whatever), can it still do that or does it have no need to do that since the main mail server will handle all of that?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I still get "Relay access denied", which I assume is because the domain I am using to send the test email is not in the domain list, however if I add that, I am back to the original problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "still"? Did you get that before? If so, please edit your question to mention that. Include the precise message you get, and describe the circumstances under which you get it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really mean "still". I just mean that you cannot seem to set relay_host without also specifying which domains to accept. I think I now appreciate that allowing all domains would be bad anyway so I need instead to find out how to sync a "database" of domains across all servers so we can automate this.

Answer (score 0):

your "backup" mailserver needs to know what mail it should accept and what it should refuse, due to spam rules, spf/dkim failures, etc.

If you simply accept and forward everything you could even get into a blacklist, because you could seem an open relay, even if you don't really deliver them.

If I were you I would prepare a secondary mailserver with a higher priority MX record configured to accept no more than what you would accept on the primary.

If you're using postfix you can use a transport map to specify how to deliver your mail to your primary server.

Comment: I'm not forwarding everything to real mailboxes, they are all going into one of our mail boxes so I don't see how we would be blacklisted. This doesn't really answer my original question which relates to have potentially 100s of domains cnaming to our server and not wanting to synchronize domain databases between multiple mail servers.

Comment: If you accept mail for every destination you would look like an open relay. And this is enough to be blacklisted, even if you do not really deliver.
I suspect that would be also a violation of RFC protocol: at the end you reply with a 250 mail accepted...